# VBA error 13 type missmatch

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with three 500K+ rows sheets on five different workbooks and on my way to extracting the data I need I came up with the following code:

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim lngFirstRow As Long, lngLastRow As Long, cRow As Long, lngNextDestRow As Long
Dim jbs As Date
Dim shSrc As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet

Set shDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheeet1")  '''Feuille de destination (sheetDestination)
lngNextDestRow = 2

   For Each shSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   Nom = shSrc.Name
    If Nom <> "Sheeet2" Then
        With shSrc

            lngFirstRow = 2
            lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=.Cells.Cells(1), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

            For cRow = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow Step 1
                jbs = .Cells(cRow, 2)
                    If jbs <> .Cells(cRow - 1, 2).Value Then
                        .Range("B" & cRow).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("A" & lngNextDestRow)
                        .Range("D" & cRow).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("B" & lngNextDestRow)
                        .Range("D" & cRow + 1).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("C" & lngNextDestRow)
                        .Range("E" & cRow).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("D" & lngNextDestRow)
                        .Range("E" & cRow + 1).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("E" & lngNextDestRow)
                        .Range("F" & cRow).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("F" & lngNextDestRow)
                        .Range("F" & cRow + 1).Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("G" & lngNextDestRow)
                        lngNextDestRow = lngNextDestRow + 1
                    End If
            Next cRow
        End With
    End If
Next shSrc
End Sub
```

This does what I need. I just modify it little by little to make the processing of the five workbooks faster. Here I extract the data in a new sheet on the same workbook.

1) It seems to work but after the whole process is done I keep getting " jbs = .Cells(cRow, 2) " highlighted and an error 13 type. Any idea how to fix this?

2) Someone provided me with this line:

```
lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=.Cells.Cells(1), LookAt:=xlPart,    LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
```

Is there any way to find the number of the last filled row in a list of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `jbs` is declared a `Date`. When you get your error, `.Cells(cRow,2)` is referring to a cell that does not contain a date or a floating point number that could be converted to a date.

Assuming that you don't care what *kind* of values you're looking at in column 2, replace:

```
            jbs = .Cells(cRow, 2)
                If jbs <> .Cells(cRow - 1, 2).Value Then
```

With:

```
                If .Cells(cRow, 2) <> .Cells(cRow - 1, 2) Then
```

That eliminates declaring `jbs` and the typing altogether.

2. `lngLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: So I should declare jbs as something else? maybe variant?

Comment: Actually the loop in column 2 is supposed to check if one day have passed or not. If the date is different from the precedent, then do the stuff in the middle, for just the first two row, then go on to the next day.
I'll try without the jbs variable if their is no need for it

Comment: Shouldn't be a need for it, but if you're getting a type mismatch, that indicates you have a non-date in your date column. May want to check your data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it happens at the end of the loop, because if my  variable IngLastRow was wrong, the loop might have gone through some blank cell. I'll try and update. Thanks!

Comment: If you're hitting the last row  & it's blank, then: `For cRow = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow - 1`. Also `Step 1` is the default so you don't need that unless you like to be really, really complete.

Comment: It works like a charm! 
Any idea how to get this program to the next level and make it work to extract the data from 5 specific workbook that are in the same folder? 
For each workbook i need the data destination to be a sheet in a new workbook, which will also host the program.

Comment: Take a shot at it. If you get stuck post a new question with your code and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

### Find row of the last used cell on the sheet

The code for `lngLastRow` you are using, will return a row of the last used cell on the sheet. Not necessarily last used cell in column "B" which you are comparing later in your code, for example here : `If jbs <> .Cells(cRow - 1, 2).Value Then...`

### Find row of the last used cell in column "B"

If you want to find last used row in column "B" with this method use : `lngLastRow = .columns(2).Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row`
That should get rid of the loop error, because it will properly stop when it should.

---

Sources :

1. [Application.Columns Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195212%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
2. [Range.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178845%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I'm starting to understand this find function a little better! 
Also, it works fine doing " If .Cells(cRow, 2) <> .Cells(cRow - 1, 2) Then ". 
I am now at the last stage of this, thanks to you